# Swift handle touch in certain location - GameScene class

Tags: ios, swift

I want to detect touches that are made in certain areas of the screen, and associate a determined action for each area that has been touched.

something like this:

[image: 3 areas that are touchable, and each one has a different action]

my code so far is this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        attackInTouch(heroAtlas) //function that gives me the animation of "attack"

    }
}
```

Normally the hero is running, and on every touch he "attacks" (an animation is shown) but i want to declare zones to handle the touch position, and then activate the action that corresponds

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create some `SKSpriteNodes` which represent your areas. After that you can check if the user has pressed on the specified node.

First you have to set the name of your SKSpritenodes:

yourNode.name = "fire"

After that you can check in your `touchesBegan` method if your node was touched:

```
let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
let node:SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

if(node.name == "specialNode"){
  //do something with your specialnode
}else if(node.name == "fire"){
  //do something with your fire-node
}
```